# xr package and pgfplots/tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, xr

I'm using tikz/pgfplots to draw my figures. Usually, my figure is a standalone file that I compile and in my main file, I simply import the pdf with `\includegraphcis`.

I now want to refer to curve in a plot such that the line/marker is printed in the text. I know that I can use `\label{...}` and `\ref{...}` for this. If the tikz-picture is in the main file, this works.

However, I would like to keep my setup where the figure is compiled standalone. I know that I can import extra aux-files in my main-file with the xr-package. It works to refer to sections, and so on. However, when I try to refer to a labeled curve, the main file does not build.

Let me give you a minimal example.

The main file:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\externaldocument[test:]{testfigure}

\begin{document}

Test: \ref{test:pgfplots:label1}

\end{document}
```

The figure file testfigure.tex:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, shapes, calc, spy}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween, groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}
\addplot+{4*cos(deg(x))};
\label{pgfplots:label1}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I compile `main.tex`, I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ... \pgfplots@show@ref@pgfplots:label1

l.9 Test: \ref{test:pgfplots:label1}
```

Can someone help me how to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! The `\ref` and `\label` system get changed in `pgfplots`, see p. 265 of the manual. What precisely do you want to achieve? If you wish to use the features of pgfplots in the main document, you need to load it there, too.

Comment: Thanks!

I want to display the linestyle (font, thickness, marker) in the text, just as in the legend.

I tried adding the same preamble as in ```testfigure.tex``` in ```main.tex```.
Unfortunately, the error persists.